# Dynamically changing the linearlayout width or height on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to change linear layout or any other widget width or height dynamically but throwing exception.

My layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="ghghjkgj ghjg hjgj ghj g hjgjgh jhg "
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and My activity is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.abc);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30,60));
    }
```

Throwing following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16052): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(16052):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So how can I change the dimensions dynamically?

Answer (score 63):

Check this - http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/04/changing-layout-height-dynamically.html

```
ll.getLayoutParams().height = 300;
ll.getLayoutParams().width = 200;
ll.requestLayout();
```

This works also on event handler.

Comment: it works, but something that should be remembered is that the view should have a parent, otherwise getLayoutParams() will return null

Comment: px but you can convert it into dp

Answer (score 30):

The problem here is that when you set the layout params the type needs to be that of the parent, in this case that is a FrameLayout. You need to do this:

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(30,60));
```

Comment: thanks a lot.......its very helpful to me but how can I identify the parent of linearlayout.

Answer (score 9):

This simple way to do your task:

```
setContentView(R.id.main);    
LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left);
int width=60;
int height=60;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
layout.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

and another way if you want to give screen size in height and width then use below code :

```
setContentView(R.id.main);    
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left);
int width=display.getWidth();
int height=display.getHeight();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new inearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
layout.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

hope use full to you.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this method inside your utils class to set height and width dynamically.**

```
 public void setWidthAndHeight(Context context,RelativeLayout view,int width, int height) {
                width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, width, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());//used to convert you width integer value same as dp
                height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, height, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
               //note : if your layout is LinearLayout then use LinearLayout.LayoutParam
                view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
         }
```