# Change height of view inside home screen widget

Tags: android, android-studio, widget

I´m pretty new to widgets in Android and I´m struggling a little to find a way to resize views inside of the widget. I´m trying to create like a volume chart where I add imageviews to a linear layout. Is this even possible? Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. Please add an image of what you're trying to achieve + add your XML attempt to achieve it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/m9MF7Al. You can see in this image at the bottom where the green/red candles are. It´s a linear layout that I add a lot of image views to (You can´t have view in widgets). I would like to have different height on these candles depending on volume value. There is no param.height when working with widgets. You have to use like
views.setInt(R.id.img_test,"setBackgroundResource",R.drawable.volume_candle_border_price_down)

I´m wondering if there is anything similar to adjust height of a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around by setting the top padding to reduce the height. They always start at maximum height

Answer (score 0):

You can change the layout height dynamically to say, x by using

```
getLayoutParams().height= x;
requestLayout(); or invalidate();
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821671/dynamically-changing-the-linearlayout-width-or-height-on-android) I found can help you to get more input, to solve your problem.

Comment: I need to dynamically change the height of a view so it can´t be done in the xml since views are being added to the linear layout in code. Watch image where the green/red candles are
https://imgur.com/a/m9MF7Al

Comment: I updated my answer. I think that could be interesting. Sorry for late response. :)