# How do I get the bottom navigation bar height for Material Design 3?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material-design-3

I'm using a Material Design 3 [bottom navigation bar](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/overview).

```xml
<!-- activity_main.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        tools:ignore="FragmentTagUsage" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've added a [floating action button (FAB)](https://m3.material.io/components/floating-action-button/overview).

```xml
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_a_vehicle_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/fab_content_description"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />
```

However, the FAB is obscured behind the navigation bar.

[image: Bottom navigation bar with obscured FAB]

I've tried to solving the issue by adding margin to the fragment following: [How to get the ActionBar height?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838143/11809808).

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    ....
    android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    ... />
```

However, that height is from the [Material Design 2 bottom navigation bar](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation) and my FAB gets cut off because it's not enough margin.

[image: Bottom navigation bar with FAB cutoff]

*How do I obtain the height of the Material Design 3 bottom navigation bar so I can display my FAB correctly?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Material3 the `BottomNavigationView` has a different `minHeight`.
You can apply something like:

```
   <fragment
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/m3_bottom_nav_min_height"
```

[image]

Reference: [android/material/bottomnavigation/res/values/dimens.xml#L32](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/f2eaf0c40a57c67ecca8b3de7032701d683ce4f3/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/res/values/dimens.xml#L32)

Comment: Thank you! That works. However, when I do use that value, it says it's private: "The resource @dimen/m3_bottom_nav_min_height is marked as private in com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0". Is that going to create any issues?

Comment: @RyanPayne No, it is only a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to get the height programmatically and set margin bottom dynamically during runtime?

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    navBar.getLayoutParams().height = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264268/how-do-i-get-the-height-and-width-of-the-android-navigation-bar-programmatically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821671/dynamically-changing-the-linearlayout-width-or-height-on-android) for more info.

Comment: When I log this value I get 44. The value of ?android:attr/actionBarSize is 56. It needs to be larger than 56.